# Hölder space with negative exponent

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory, holder-spaces

The definition of the Hölder space with positive exponent is well-known. Namely  we say that a function $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ belong to the Hölder space $\mathcal {C}^{\alpha}$ ($\alpha>0$), if $f$ has $[\alpha]$ continuous derivatives and it's $[\alpha]$-th derivative (that we denote here by $f^{([\alpha])}$) satisfies
$$
\|f\|_\alpha:=\|f\|_\infty+\sup_{s,t\in\mathbb{R}}\frac{|f^{([\alpha])}(t)-f^{([\alpha])}(s)|}{|t-s|^{\alpha-[\alpha]}}<\infty.
$$

As usual, $[\alpha]$ denotes the integer part of a real $\alpha$.

It is also clear that if $f\in\mathcal{C}^\alpha$, then $f'\in\mathcal{C}^{\alpha-1}$, $\alpha>1$.

My question is how can one extend this definition for negative $\alpha$. Let $f\in\mathcal{C}^{1/2}$. Then its derivative $g:=f'$ is a generalized function (distribution). How one can define $\mathcal{C}^{-1/2}$, so that $f'\in\mathcal{C}^{-1/2}$?

Answer (score 1):

The straightforward approach would be to say that a distribution $f\in D'$ belongs to the class $C^{-\alpha}$ for $\alpha\in(0,1)$ there exists $F\in C^{1-\alpha}$ such that the derivative of $F$ in the sense of distributions is $f$.

However, I do not know to what kind of problems this approach presents - most notably, what you use as a norm in this space.

Answer (score 1):

Negative Holder spaces can be defined and are also used. One definition is through [Besov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Besov_space) spaces with $p, q = \infty.$ Another is straightforward through scaling properties. It turns out that a positive Holder functions scales as $\lambda^{\alpha}$ and a negative one as $\lambda^{-\alpha},$ for $\alpha \in (0,1)$ in a certain sense that can be made precise either (humbly) by my two questions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2148906/fundamental-theorem-of-calculus-for-distributions) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2119634/h%C3%B6lder-continuity-definition-through-distributions) or for example in this paper [here](https://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/maths/people/staff/hendrik_weber/lectnotes.pdf) at page 10.